# Unable to switch language in Firefox only in input-password

Tags: firefox

Have a very strange issue that I haven't encountered before,

Take for example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit and replace the `input type=text` to `password` like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
Last name: <input type="password" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For some reason, in Firefox only I'm unable to switch the languages for the `input[type=password]`, therefor, my passwords don't work in the app, in every other browser the password input works fine with switching the language ...

Also, in FF, if I change the input back to `text` - then I'm able to switch languages ...

I'm using `MacOSX` & `Firefox Quantum 65.0.1 (64-bit)`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

A similar bug in Mozilla under Mac [Can't switch keyboard layout on input type="password"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=480277) is closed as invalid, but it seems under Ubuntu it's a bug indeed.

Comment: Expericencing this on Macbook Pro Sonoma OS right now (Google Chrome). Can't belive it's still and issue in 2024.